# How to determine planet aspect when planet in different house in Bhava chakra

Tags: astrology

When a planet is in a different house in the Bhava chakra than the main (I don't know the proper term for this) chart how should we determine the planet's aspect?

Let's say we want to check the 7th aspect from a planet which is in 7th house from Lagna in the main chart but in bhava chart, it is actually in 8th, then should the planet's 7th aspect be on 1st house or the 2nd house from Lagna?

Comment: Aspect does not change, even if the planet gets a different position in the Bhava Chalit. (Because Planet has not left the house yet, Bhava chalit only says that the planet will give more effects of the house it falls into rather than the house it was into). I.e. in your example it will be first house and not the second.

Comment: @Proxy Thank you for the answer. Can you please add your answer to the answer section? Then I can mark this as answered.

Comment: No sources right now. Someone else might answer it. If I find I will...

Comment: Softwares like Jhora gives exact aspect percentage on different bhavas and planets